# install.packages in r studio but still r studio cannot find it

Tags: r

When I am trying to use

```
install.packages()
```

command to install package in r studio. At the end of the terminal after the installation finishes, I received:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/f6/4hcr4rxs4k1fnz6n34jy3xwm0000gn/T/Rtmplj9aNp/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

When I use .libPaths() to check where r studio is looking for my package, I see:

```
[1] "/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library"      
[2] "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.3/lib/R/library"
```

So since the path is different, my r studio essentially cannot find any libraries I install.

Even I use

```
install.packages(package_name, lib="xxxxxxxx")
```

It still does not work. How I should fix the problem?

My mac version is M1 chip, but I do not think this info is helpful. Just FYI

Comment: You are misinterpreting the (admittedly, confusing) R message. The packages are installed in the package library path, not in the temporary path. The part of the message *before that* (which you haven’t posted) should show where the packages are installed. Run `dir(.libPaths()[1])` to list the installed packages.

Comment: Try `installed.packages()[,c("Built","LibPath")] ` and `installed.packages() [which( installed.packages()[,"Package"] %in% c("BH","rlang")),c("Built","Version","LibPath")]` where `BH` and `rlang` are examples.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right. The package is not installed in the dir. How should I enforce the correct installation path?

Comment: install.packages("tmap", lib = "/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library" ) is not working

Comment: "Is not working" -> Is there error, or is it installed well but `library("tmap")` don't see the package ?

Comment: still don't see the package and not appear in ```dir(.libPaths()[1])```

Comment: In addition, you should generally not install packages into the site library either. Homebrew is a bit special because it assumes system-wide, user-readable installations. This isn’t the regular installation model, and it’s not great (in fact, these days I recommend against using Homebrew!). Instead, you should maintain a user package library (on macOS, its default is `~/Library/R/%p/%v/library`, where `%p` and `%v` are placeholders documented under `help(R_LIBS_USER)`).

Comment: Not entirely understand it ..... Sorry I am a bit new to this. But in general, I guess we just need to run install.packages command to get what we want right? Is there executable command which I can use to fix the problem?

Comment: You still haven’t provided enough information for us to diagnose what problem you are having. But a good solution would be to start at the beginning: uninstall R, and reinstall it using the official installer, i.e. *not* using Homebrew. Afterwards you should be able to install packages. If still not, we can go from there.